# Swipe to Delete in UITableViewCell has white background, need clear

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicolor

I am trying to change the background color of the view that appears when you swipe a UITableViewCell row, the background color behind the 'Delete' button.

I tried changing the cell.editingAccessoryView but that didn't do anything.

```
    UIView* myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.editingAccessoryView = myBackgroundView;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I'm answering this because it took me a while to find an answer and this is the first entry that comes up in a search. By using the `willDisplayCell` method you can access the cells background color. Note that `[UIColor clearColor];` will return white in so adjust your code accordingly.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there. The `UITableViewCell` class has a `backgroundView` property, which is `nil` by default. Just create a new `UIView` as you've done in your question, then assign that to the `backgroundView` property of your cell.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you are adding content into your cell.

When i added content to the cell directly using [cell addSubView] or [cell.contentView addSubView] i was having the same problem.

My workaround to this was:

```
Create a view
Add all your content(labels, images etc;) to this view
Finally then add the view to your cell using [cell addSubView:tmpView]
```

And you do not need to tamper with the backgroundView property anymore. I have tried this and works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

While these answers are right I feel that for most cases it's easier just to set the cell's background color in interface builder.  By that I mean the actual background color property of the cell, not it's content view. There's no reason to do it dynamically if it's always gonna be the color that the content view is anyway.

Answer (score 0):

iOS8 adds new method to `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

You can create customizable `UITableViewRowAction` which device your row actions.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Cancel", handler: { action, indexPath in 
         // DELETE ROW HERE
     })
    deleteAction.background = .green // you can change background color

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

For more check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowaction)

Nice example of usage new API: [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/enable-slide-to-delete-in-uitableview-9311653dfe2)

Answer (score 0):

right way, just to let everyone know:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for subview in tableView.subviews {
        if NSStringFromClass(type(of: subview)) == "UISwipeActionPullView", let button = subview.subviews.first, NSStringFromClass(type(of: button)) == "UISwipeActionStandardButton"
        {
            button.backgroundColor = .clear
            button.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```